# Scale factor not permitted in address, x86_64 Xcode 4.6

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, memory-address

I'd really like to use this address construction, which is supported according to distant memories and also everywhere I look, but for some reason it upsets my compiler/assembler.

```
mov rax, [rsi+rcx*8]
```

The compiler throws an error on the *, saying

```
error: unknown token in expression mov rax, [rsi+rcx*8]
                                                    ^
```

These instructions are completely acceptable:

```
mov rax, [rsi+rcx]; 
mov rax, [rsi+rcx+8]
```

So either the compiler doesn't support scale (as if?) or scale isn't supported in 64-bit mode?

This is in Xcode 4.6, using I presume, LLVM, though this is my first assembler project since the days of floppy drives so I'm not sure of who is doing the parsing. I do indeed have .intel_syntax specified. The asm is in an .s file, not inline.

So is x86_64 mode the problem?
From the Intel documentation, "64-bit addressing uses existing 32-bit ModR/M and SIB encodings", but does it just ignore the scale bits in the SIB byte?

Many thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, your (Intel) asm syntax looks fine to me, so it must be the tool that has some kind of quirk with this. It seems unlikely that this kind of index scaling would be totally unsupported - it's more likely that it must be specified in a different way.

Comment: Thank you, I'll leave this up to percolate & see if anyone else can suggest a syntax or knows what I'm doing incorrectly. K

Comment: Try leaving a space around the '*' - `mov rax, [rsi + rcx * 8]` ?

Comment: For some reason llvm requires the scale before the register. This works: `mov rax, [rsi+8*rcx]`.

Comment: Thanks ughoavgfhw, that does indeed work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Make that the answer.